# How do I get rid of a white frame in ViewPager sample

Tags: android, android-layout

folks!
I examined those samples from Android Compability lib. And I can't find how to remove those white frames marked red(adown and between pages):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the fragment_pager_list.xml file remove the background from the root LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"> <-- Remove this background
</LinearLayout>
```

So you have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```